# PHP script wont work when executed via command line but work fine when executed from browser

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, ubuntu-12.04

My PHP script is working very well when executed via browser but showing error message when tried to execute using Command prompt.

First I tested php file from command prompt using "system('ls >/tmp/test.txt')" in php file. It worked fine.

But when executed  Mysql query within PHP script via command prompt it's showing error.(note:  same mysql query within php file  was successfully executed from browser).

command: php fullpath____/automatic.php

error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in  fullpath_____/automatic.php on line number 7.

What is the problem ?

Comment: post your code ... i think mysqli_connect() need params

Comment: @rdn87 The error says that the function does not exist, this isn't caused by insufficient parameters.

Comment: @KaloyanDoichinov i think the same ;)

Answer (score 0):

Note that PHP may use completely different configurations for the CLI (command-line) version and the one that the webserver forwards to (for example, PHP-FPM)

That error means that the mysql extension is not enabled for PHP's CLI configuration. Login as a privileged user and try this:
`sudo php5enmod mysql`, after that is should work.

Comment: I tried mention command. But got error message: Command not found.

Comment: I am able to find "sudo php5enmod mcrypt" command by google search. Command mention above is different from this?

Answer (score 0):

php command line uses diferent php.ini than php browser.
You must have installed pdo_mysql extension.
In linux system the command line php.ini is in

```
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

And the browser php.ini is in

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Check that you have in that files

```
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Comment: i checked files but didn't get "extension=pdo_mysql.so". Whether I have need to write same line in php.ini or need  to install it?

Comment: or also wanna know in which file from both php.ini , I have to add this line.

Comment: Got  error after adding  "extension=pdo_mysql.so".     "                                            PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/pdo_mysqli.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/pdo_mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: You have to install php-mysql. If you have ubuntu or debian install with `sudo apt-get install php-mysql`.

Comment: it seems by adding complete path of php in command solved my problem. ll update soon after complete confirmation. thanks